# List videos of interesting courses at the doctoral level.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

Many mathematics departments has provided video lessons their courses (usually one semester) that are offered in their doctoral programs in mathematics. Most often these courses total average of 26 videos each containing a single class.  Below is a list of introdutory courses on video.

- [Introduction to Algebraic Topology](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdpbfOzkJzI)
- [Introduction to Lie Algebras](http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=programa-de-verao-2011-introduction-to-lie-algebra)
- [Extremal and Probabilistic Combinatorics](http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=programa-de-mestrado-2012-extremal-and-probabilistic-combinatorics)

I would appreciate if people could add on to this list.

**Observation** To a greater audience reach classes should preferably be in English language and introdutory curses.

**Observation** I will not be specific as to the area of investigation. Since I believe that the answers here will be useful for students who are not my area of interest. But I have a preference for introdutory courses of Ergodic Theory, Probability, Stochastic Processes, Combinatorics and Statistical Mechanics.

Comment: Could you be more specific of what areas you are interested in? The whole point of doctoral level courses is that they generally dispense of the basics.

Comment: @Alex I will not be specific as to the area of investigation. Since I believe that the answers here will be useful for students who are not my area of interest. But I have a preference for courses ergodic theory, Probability, Stochastic Processes, Combinatorics and Statistical Mechanics.

Comment: I think that from the three examples you gave @Elias, at least the first two are basic stuff from first-second graduate year at most. Yes, they can serve as basis to develop some research, but I'd hardly identify them as PhD material per se, though *some* subjects in them (as in almost any other area) can be, of course.

Comment: @DonAntonio, well the videos I listed in my question is just to illustrate my point

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm slightly puzzled by your comment.  If something is from the "first-second graduate year", isn't it by definition at the doctoral level?  What is the distinction between "PhD material" and material in courses offered as part of a PhD program?

Comment: Well, at least in my alma mater, one thing is the first two graduate years (for a master degree) and another one the doctoral courses which can be chosen, depending on the branch one chooses, from graduate courses. We had three huge courses of which two were compulsory for everybody: Algebra, Algebraic Topology, and Functional Analysis, with their subcourses, one of which was Lie Algebras and Representations. This already covers two of the three given links, and one could apply for these courses even at advanced undergraduate level (depending on the optional courses one took)

Comment: @DonAntonio  Perhaps this varies by country? Most of the Ph.D. programs I'm aware of (in the United States) accept students who just received their undergraduate degree, and little distinction is made between the levels of different graduate courses.  Of course, there are some courses (such as Algebraic Topology) that are usually taken by 1st-year and 2nd-year Ph.D. students, but in my mind these are the very definition of "doctoral level" courses.

Comment: I think you're right, @JimBelk . We also have doctoral program right after undergraduate studies, yet these students can become instructors only after the first two graduate complete years (the equivalent of a M. Sc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very much related [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free) on MathOverflow with a lot of links.