# Online course in representation theory or differential geometry

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, representation-theory

Are there any courses in representation theory that are available online? I'm looking for a course including videos, notes as well as assignments. I'd also be interested in a course in differential geometry. I couldn't find anything. The MIT open courseware courses are all without video.

Comment: For the course credit, the material, or both? (While there are numerous freely available notes and texts for representation theory and differential geometry online, I don't follow educational videos  so can't answer the question myself.)

Comment: @anon The material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/391851/73025) and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free).

In particular:

- [Introduction to Lie Algebras](http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=programa-de-verao-2011-introduction-to-lie-algebra)
- [Representation theory](http://www.youtube.com/user/amriprasad#grid/user/FE2F2CDA55A9EBB6)
- [Differential geometry](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search.php?activityid=MTH&course=Differential_Geometry)

Comment: The third link does not contain any video??

Answer (score 1):

Norman Wildberger has his entire course for Differential Geometry on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIljB45xT85DWUiFYYGqJVtfnkUFWkKtP

Please note that he does take some non-traditional routes, but I believe this enhances his approach. The course is aimed at undergraduates and covers a lot of traditional material.